# How to use $lt and $gte in a query in mongoDb

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this problem. I have this database:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58c1a000023409b3b4263c69"),
"nome" : "hotel",
"point" : [ 
    {
        "nome" : "hall",
        "wiFi" : [ 
            {
                "ssid" : "ssjjt",
                "bssid" : "c0:04:25:83:06:30",
                "rssid" : "-77",
            }, 
            {
                "ssid" : "spot",
                "bssid" : "b8:03:05:3a:80:af",
                "rssid" : "-34",
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "nome" : "restorant",
        "wiFi" : [ 
            {
                "ssid" : "ssjjt",
                "bssid" : "c0:04:25:83:06:30",
                "rssid" : "-76",
            }
        ]
}
```

and I have the following `rssid` values in PHP, the max and the min like

```
min : -70
max : - 80
```

I would  like to have a query which give to me a list of values that has the surveys between my two values.

I have to use an aggregate query.

Thanks you so much guys.

Comment: Can you please add an example showing the expected JSON result set you want the query to return?  That will help get a more precise answer.

Comment: hello, thanks to help me. i would like to have a list like ["hall" , "restorant"]. <br> this two values are the values with the rssid included in the default values and have the same ssid and own of hotel strutture. i hope to have explained to you in the best way. could you help me?

Comment: Is it an option for you to change the db and store rssid as a number instead of a string? Or to have an additional numeric field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you have rssids stored as Strings in your database and you cannot apply $lt and $gte to compare them with Numeric values as Mongo is strict regarding the types.

There is also no easy way to convert a string to a number during the aggregation. As for example $where clause is not allowed during the aggregation.

The first way to achieve what you want is to modify the databse to keep rssid as Numbers (or keep the original strings and have an additional numeric property) and then run an aggregation like this.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$point'},
    {$match: {'point.wiFi.rssid': {$gte: -80, $lt: -70}}},
    //You can omit grouping if you don't need them to be unique
    {$group: {_id: '$point.nome'}}
])
```

The second way comes into play if you cannot modify the database or add a property. You can use a mapReduce. For example:

```js
db.getCollection('test').mapReduce(function () {
        this.point = this.point || [];
        this.point.forEach(function (point) {
            point.wiFi = point.wiFi || [];
            point.wiFi.forEach(function (wiFi) {
                var rssid = parseInt(wiFi.rssid);

                if (rssid >= -80 && rssid < -70) {
                    emit(point.nome, rssid);
                }
            })
        });
    },
    function (key) {
        return key;
    },
    {out: {inline: 1}}
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Antonio. I changed the value from String to Int in the db and i used the first method . it work.  Thank you again